# image unclear after downloading using python urlretrieve

Tags: python, image, download

```
import urllib.request
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
def dl_image(url):
    name="test1"
    full_name = name + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)
dl_image("https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3667/32598752764_b62a07cf43_n.jpg")
```

this code works but the photo i'm getting is not at good resolution.
where am i doing it wrong??

Also is it legal to download images from flickr using this method?

the site has a download button on the images

Answer (score 0):

The image at https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3667/32598752764_b62a07cf43_n.jpg is 320x240, so it's not good resolution to start with... Trying something high-res, such as [this](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-lFCODfTM4PQ/T_pe0x_t4qI/AAAAAAAAESU/CsxziAC8RcU/s1600/Beautiful+dog+hd+Wallpapers_3.jpg), downloads high quality images. Downloading it this way should be no different than downloading it from your browser (disclaimer: I'm not a copyright lawyer).

Comment: i figured because the code was very simple it can't go wrong,your picture worked great